# ng-repeat causing delay in Ionic app (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my controller, I have an object (`sorted_users`) containing the name and linkedIn ID of people, sorted alphabetically:

```
{
  "A":[
    {"Name":"an something","linkedInID":"..."},
    {"Name":"arthur somethingelse","linkedInID":"..."},
    {"Name":"ashton lastname","linkedInID":"..."}],
  "B":[
    {"Name":"ben blabla","linkedInID":"..."},
    {"Name":"bianca someone","linkedInID":"..."},
    {"Name":"borris random","linkedInID":"..."},
... and so on
```

My html:

```
<div ng-repeat="(letter, names) in sorted_users" class="alpha_list">
    <ion-item class="item item-divider" id="index_{{letter}}">
        {{letter}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="n in names | filter :{Name:search}">
        <h2>{{n.Name}}
            <i class="icon ion-social-linkedin" ng-if="n.linkedInID" ng-click="openlinkedin(n.linkedInID)"></i></h2>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

While this works, I'm getting performance issues when there are +400 people. Clicking on the link that links to the page where the people should be, results in a pause of 3-4 seconds. After that, the animation kicks in and the app navigates to the people page.

I used to show the people without the alphabet divider. My array looked like this:

```
[
   {"Name":"an something","linkedInID":"..."},
   {"Name":"arthur somethingelse","linkedInID":"..."},
   {"Name":"ashton lastname","linkedInID":"..."},
   {"Name":"ben blabla","linkedInID":"..."},
   {"Name":"bianca someone","linkedInID":"..."},
   {"Name":"borris random","linkedInID":"..."},
... and so on
```

And in my html, I could use collection-repeat:

```
    <ion-item class="item-icon-right" collection-repeat="n in unsorted | filter :{Name:search}">
        <h2>{{n.Name}}
            <i class="icon ion-social-linkedin" ng-if="n.linkedInID" ng-click="openlinkedin(n.linkedInID)"></i></h2>
    </ion-item>
```

This removes the performance issues, but doesn't allow me to put alphabetical dividers.

I see two solutions that would satisfy my needs:

---

### **Possible solution 1:**

Using collection-repeat with the `sorted_users`. I'm unable to get this to work: `collection-repeat expected an array for 'sorted_users', but got a undefined`

---

### **Possible solution 2:**

Showing a loading spinner when clicking the button, and after the delay, remove it again to navigate to the page.
I've tried adding this to my controller:

```
$scope.gotopeople = function()
{
    $ionicLoading.show({
        content: 'Processing...',
        template: "<ion-spinner></ion-spinner><br />Processing...",
        showBackdrop: true,
        showDelay: 0
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        window.location="...link to people page...";
    }, 100);
};
```

And then:

```
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function(){
        $ionicLoading.hide();

    });
```

This seems to work, but during the delay, the spinner freezes and stops "spinning". It's there, but it looks like the app crashes (which isn't the case).

Comment: `ng-repeat="(letter, names) in sorted_users" track by $index` should help you with the performance problem. When you do a ng-repeat, dont forget to add "track by something", it's really faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried adding `track by $index` but the performance is the same.

Comment: you have another ng-repeat to treat: `collection-repeat="n in unsorted | filter :{Name:search}"` The filter is called lots of time and if you have code which takes time to be executed, it decrease significally the performances. Remove that filter to test, then you will have to create an array and update it when you modify the search.

Comment: I tried removing the filter part for testing, but the performance stays the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load your list in several times thanks-to

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
 ng-if="moreDataCanBeLoaded()"
 on-infinite="loadMore()"
 distance="1%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: I have anchors on the letter dividers to jump to certain letters. My guess is that infinite-scroll will screw those up...